# Find the number of non-negative integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 < 16$ if all the values have to be greater than or equal to 2.

Tags: combinatorics

I understand how stars and bars work when the question is $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 16.$ How do I go about it when instead of the equals to, there is either a $<$ or a $\leq$ sign?

Comment: Let $y_i=x_i-2$, so now $\sum y_i<6$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: @lulu not really. I'm not sure how to go about it with a less-than sign.

Comment: Well, you could always just sum the cases.  There are so few.  Edit your post to show the result computed that way.  There is a trick to do it quicker, but the direct method is so easy, why not start there?

Comment: Once you've defined $y_i=x_i-2,$ the equation can be rewritten as $$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5\leq 5,$$ for $y_i\geq 0.$

But this is equal to the number of solutions of:

$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_6=5,$$

for $y_i\geq 0.$

Answer (score 2):

It is the most elementary technique I know. Once $2\leq x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ we have
$$
10\leq x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 
$$
By $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 <16$ we have $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\leq 15$. Note that:

- The number of solutions for
  $
  x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=10
  $
  is
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \text{permutations}  \\
  \text{of elements $2$} \\
  \text{in $5$ positions} \\
  \text{$2$ have $5$ repetitions} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \frac{5!}{0!5!}=1
  $$
  Explicitly they are $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(2,2,2,2,2)$.
- The number of solutions for
  $
  x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=11
  $
  is equal to
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \text{permutations}  \\
  \text{of elements $2$ and $3$} \\
  \text{in $5$ positions} \\
  \text{$2$ have $4$ repetitions} \\
  \text{$3$ have $1$ repetition} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \frac{5!}{1!4!}=5
  $$
  Explicitly they are
  $$
  (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(2,2,2,2,3)\\
  (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(2,2,2,3,2)\\
  (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(2,2,3,2,2)\\
  (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(2,3,2,2,2)\\
  (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(3,2,2,2,2)\\
  $$
- The number of solutions for
  $
  x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=12
  $
  is equal to
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \text{permutations}  \\
  \text{of elements $2$ and $4$} \\
  \text{in $5$ positions} \\
  \text{$2$ have $4$ repetitions} \\
  \text{$4$ have $1$ repetition} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  +
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \text{permutations}  \\
  \text{of elements $2$ and $3$} \\
  \text{in $5$ positions} \\
  \text{$2$ have $3$ repetitions} \\
  \text{$3$ have $2$ repetition} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \frac{5!}{1!4!}+\frac{5!}{2!3!}=5+10=15
  $$
- The number of solutions for
  $
  x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=13
  $
  is equal to
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \text{permutations}  \\
  \text{of elements $2$ and $5$} \\
  \text{in $5$ positions} \\
  \text{$2$ have $4$ repetitions} \\
  \text{$5$ have $1$ repetition} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  +
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \text{permutations}  \\
  \text{of elements $2$,$3$ and $4$} \\
  \text{in $5$ positions} \\
  \text{$2$ have $3$ repetitions} \\
  \text{$3$ have $1$ repetition} \\
  \text{$4$ have $1$ repetition} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  +
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \text{permutations}  \\
  \text{of elements $2$ and $3$} \\
  \text{in $5$ positions} \\
  \text{$2$ have $1$ repetitions} \\
  \text{$3$ have $3$ repetition} \\
  \text{$4$ have $1$ repetition} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  =\\
  \frac{5!}{1!4!}+\frac{5!}{2!3!}+\frac{5!}{1!3!1!}=5+10+20=35
  $$
  Now the rest is up to you. I hope I have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

As Lulu pointed out, $\sum y_i<6$ will happen when you perform the substitution $x_i=y_i+2$

But since all variables are integers we rewrite this as (what Thomas said) $$\sum y_i\le5$$ Introducing the dummy variable yields $$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_6=5$$ So basically you have to find all non negative integer solutions to the above expression. That is simply $$\binom{5+6-1}{6-1}$$
$$=\binom{10}{5}$$
$$=252$$

Comment: What is wrong in my answer?

Comment: Nothing wrong. Looks the better of the two to me.

Comment: That the introduction of $y_6$ makes the number of solution equal to $\sum_{i=1}^6 y_i=5$ may not be that obvious. Probably that's why there is no check mark.

Comment: @JAP I've used the standard technique

Comment: Essentially you have juxtaposed two comments. Yes, the whole problem is standard, but posting a link or quick explanation to that step would add a lot of value to your answer.